# What ARIA roles and attributes are appropriate for a non-semantic table?

Tags: html, wai-aria

I am rendering tables of data in two ways, one using semantic table tags and the other a non-semantic groups of `<div>`s using css `display: table` and the like.

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-header">
    <div class="table-header-row">
      <div class="table-header-cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-body">
    <div class="table-body-row">
      <div class="table-body-cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would still like the non-semantic table to be as accessible as possible, so I am wondering what combination of ARIA attributes I can use to describe to the user that they are interacting with a table or something table-like?  I have never seen a role of "table" "table-row" or anything like that.. so i am not sure if i understand correctly what is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#grid

> grid (role)
>
> A grid is an interactive control which contains cells of tabular data
>   arranged in rows and columns, like a table.

See also [treegrid](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#treegrid), [row](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#row), [rowgroup](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#rowgroup), [gridcell](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#gridcell), [rowheader](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#rowheader) and [columnheader](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#columnheader)

However, if these are appropriate, then you should probably be using an HTML table.

Comment: oh man "grid".. i probably would not have guessed that.. thanks!

Comment: "if these are appropriate, then you should probably be using an HTML table".. true and i do, whenever possible.  the non semantic tables are used only when i need a "table-like" structure but with js/jquery need extra UI control that a <table> just does not have.  THough I would still like it to be accessible compliant.